# How to check if locals are defined in a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the correct syntax to test if locals have been defined and passed to a partial?

For example, I render a partial

```
<%= render partial: "data-map", locals: {lat: @model.lat, lon: @model.lon, zoom: 10} %>
```

And in the partial need to do something like

```
<%= map( options: {
  latitude: if lat.defined? ? lat : 0,
  longitude: if lon.defined? ? lon : 0,
  zoom: if zoom.defined? ? zoom : 50
  }
%>
```

I'm having trouble getting this working.

I also saw the following in the API

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :headline %>
  Headline: <%= headline %>
<% end %>
```

but am having trouble with this as well. Perhaps I'm not getting the syntax correct.

Grateful for any pointers

Comment: I did not know about `local_assigns`.  I found out about it from this question.  I was able to use `local_assigns[:some_var] || some_default`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the if from the ternary format as follows:

```
<%= map( options: {
  latitude: defined?(lat) ? lat : 0,
  longitude: defined?(lon) ? lon : 0,
  zoom: defined?(zoom) ? zoom : 50
  }
%>
```

Comment: thanks anil. this gives `undefined method 'defined?'`. There was another answer here just now, which worked. Seems to have been deleted though. I used `defined?(lat) ? lat : 0`.

Comment: I guess you had two issues. 1. The syntax for the ternary if. 2. Syntax of defined?. defined? is followed by a variable to see if it is defined. Does it work as shown?

Comment: I have re-factored and tested this answer. Please confirm that it works for you too. Thanks.

Comment: just made a minor edit to reflect the syntax I'm using. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I approved the edit. For part 2 of your question. try this: latitude: local_assigns.has_key?(:lat) ? lat : 0 etc

Comment: Thanks anil, sorry my question wasn't very clear. I was looking at `local_assigns` because I had got the impression that `defined?` would not work on locals passed to partials. But I was wrong. Thanks for your help.